# How can I get datetime value from MYSQL database on my hosting

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I must send datetime value from my app to API on hosting server and get **all dates value** later datetime (which was sent from app) from database table on my hosting to String and show it dates in Log.

**DB_Functions.php**

```
/**
     * Get dates from database
     */
    public function getDate_of_upload_file($date_of_upload_file) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM docs WHERE created_at = '$date_of_upload_file_phone'") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        }
        return $result;
    }
```

**index.php**

```
// Checking dates of documents

if ($tag == 'date_of_documents') {



$date_of_upload_file = $_POST['date_of_upload_file'];



// check for documents

$date_of_upload_file = $db->getDate_of_upload_file($date_of_upload_file);

if ($date_of_upload_file != false) {

    // documents found

    // echo json with success = 1

    $response["success"] = 1;
$response["user"]["date_of_upload_file"] = $user["date_of_upload_file"];



    echo json_encode($response);

} else {

    // documents not found

    // echo json with error = 1

    $response["error"] = 1;

    $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect date_of_upload_file!";

    echo json_encode($response);

    }

}
```

**UserFunctions.java**

```
/**
 * Function to Get Date of Document
 **/

public JSONObject get_data_of_upload_file(){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", documents_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date_of_upload", date_of_upload));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    return json;
    }
```

**Main.java**

```
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.get_data_of_upload_file();
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Great. What's the problem?

Comment: My code works untrue.